# Trouble using Reddit's API

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, reddit

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error when I run this:
https://codeshare.io/5vwLxk

What am I doing wrong with the request? My postData is, and should be:

`?grant_type=https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client&device_id=df24a7a1-a1d2-4eca-b378-3668e3592007`

The url passed to WWW is: `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token`

Putting it together should be a valid API call, but it gives me an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

On lines 86 and 93 of that script, you call `StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));` seemingly expecting that call to block until the request finishes, which means you're returning the WWW value from the POST method before the request has been completed.

EDIT: GET and POST need to be themselves Coroutines, and should call some "RequestComplete" function at the end of the methods.

EDIT: I've rewritten the class structure to show a way of getting the WWW object after the request has been complete: https://codeshare.io/GLwk36

Comment: What's the right way to do it? That part seems to work.

Comment: Are you getting the 500 error on line 44 or line 104?

Comment: 104. I added that just to try to test what it ended up being.

Comment: try moving `WWW www = new WWW(url);` to the start of the WaitForRequest method (probably a long shot, but some unity methods are designed to be called from certain methods). Also, did you print the data to varify it's what reddit expects you to send?

Comment: Yeah that's what Debug.Log() does. It gives me the post data, which I mentioned, correctly.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean when you say move the statement. It already defines a WWW called www in the parameters, and the GET method needs to return something. Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: I think the issue may lie at the end of your parametersToArray method. I doubt binaryformatter serializes a string to the correct encoding. Try using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString())` to encode the string to a byte array instead. replace UTF8 with the encoding required by Reddit (It's either UTF-8 or ASCII).

Comment: I did that part (didn't convert GET and POST to IEnumerators) and I'm getting Error 401 unauthorized instead of Error 500. My uuid doesn't matter, and my key is correct so I have no idea what's going wrong now....

Comment: Also, that Base64Encode isn't doing anything. It's converting it back to whatever encoding (probably UTF-8) the program uses when it converts it from a base64 byte array to a string. The string class does not store what encoding it was serialized from. You can only choose what encoding to use when you serialize a string to a byte array with System.Convert or the Encoding.<encoding>.GetBytes methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't actually display the result using your IEnumerable functions. I'll work more with this in the morning.

Comment: oh, forgot to change the POST(...) call to StartCoroutine(POST(...)). Could be why.

Comment: I fixed it. I need a header for Content-Type and there was a superfluous '?' in the postData.